# Identify a story in which Watch Tower was crashed on the Moon and Wonder Woman murdered a guy

Tags: story-identification, comics, dc, justice-league

I once read a comics which I am unable to recall. It was probably either issue #0 or issue #1 because I generally not read any comic from the middle of series unless there's a requirement of story arc.

Here are some points in my mind:

- Watch Tower was crashed on the Moon. Batman was investigating for the reasons.
- People were scared of Justice League because Wonder Woman killed a human when it wasn't necessary. Batman and Superman were asking its reasons to Wonder Woman at the crash site on the Moon.
- Superman asked Wonder Woman who she was. She replied "Wonder Woman". Superman said, "I still remember those days when you wanted to be called Princess Diana." (Not exact words)
- Earth was turning to hell. There were high level of crime everywhere.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That was during [Infinite Crisis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_Crisis) and the investigation of OMAC

> [Wonder Woman kills Maxwell Lord](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell_Lord#Infinite_Crisis)

Comment: Surprisingly I actually read **a lot** of Infinite Crisis. So I recognized this story almost immediately.

Comment: That kill was the literal opposite of unnecessary. She asks him if there's *anything* she can to to stop him short of killing him. He's bound by the Lasso and says no.